# Converting a many-to-many relationship to one-to-many in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a many-to-many between `foo` and `bar` modeled as a table `foo_bar` with `foo_id` and `bar_id`.

I'd now like to model this as a one-to-many (which my data allows).

I've added a `foo_id` column to `bar` but now I want to migrate my data. So, I want to

```
UPDATE bar SET foo_id = f where id = b;
```

where each `f` and `b` pair are coming from

```
SELECT foo_id AS f, bar_id AS b FROM foo_bar;
```

Is it possible to do this in SQL (and specifically PostgreSQL 9.0)?

I know how to do sub-SELECTs in UPDATEs when there's only one value, but stumped how to do it in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE bar b
SET    foo_id = fb.foo_id
FROM   foo_bar fb
WHERE  fb.bar_id = b.bar_id;
```

If you should have multiple rows for one `bar` (which you shouldn't, according to your description) the one row will be updated multiple times and the result is arbitrary.

This form of the query generally performs better than a correlated subquery.

Note that the primary key of `bar` should really be named `bar_id` - I use that name in the query.

Comment: should last line be fb.bar_id = b.id ?

Comment: @JamesTauber: No. There shouldn't be an `id` in the model. Using the non-descriptive column name `id` is an anti-pattern. The primary key should be named `bar_id`.

Comment: fair enough, was just mapping it to the specifics of my question

Answer (score 4):

You can still join tables in `UPDATE` statements, try

```
UPDATE  bar a
SET     foo_id = c.foo_id
FROM    (
            SELECT foo_id, bar_id
            FROM foo_bar
        ) c
WHERE   a.id = c.bar_id
```

or simply as

```
UPDATE  bar a
SET     foo_id = c.foo_id
FROM    foo_bar c
WHERE   a.id = c.bar_id
```

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter actually this is not tested. does postgre that strict enough? hehe, so in this case i should rewrite it to `SET     foo_id = c.foo_id`?"

Comment: Exactly: `SET foo_id = c.foo_id`, like in my answer. I quote the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html): `Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column — for example, UPDATE tab SET tab.col = 1 is invalid.`

Answer (score 2):

If you really have a 1-many relationship, then it doesn't matter which value of foo you take for a given bar -- there is only one or they are all the same.

You can do the following:

```
update bar
    set foo_id = (select max(foo_id) from foo_bar where foo_bar.bar_id = bar.id)
```

The subquery limits the results to a single value.