# Refactor many-to-many relationship to many-to-one in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the following table arrangement:

A - B - C

where B is a join table between A and C.  It turns out the domain relationship between A and C is truly one to many (many on the A side), and I would like to refactor our schema to reflect this fact.

Is it possible to write a SQL UPDATE statement to insert all the correct id's of C into the proper rows of A (each row of A will have exactly one C id)?  Or is a procedure necessary?

Note: I will accept an Oracle-only answer, as that is the only place this migration will be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update tableA 
   set foreignKeyColumn = (
      select columnC 
         from tableB
         where columnA = tableA.columnA
   );
```

Actually seeing the full table structure would make it easier, but this should work.

Comment: Note for posterity: this is an Oracle-specific answer.  For PostgreSQL, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151761/converting-a-many-to-many-relationship-to-one-to-many-in-postgresql?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

```
-- assuming you have tableA (id_a), tableB (id_a,id_c), tableC (id_c)

alter table tableA add id_c int;
alter table tableA add constraint foreign key (id_c) references tableC(id_c);

merge into tableA a
using tableB b
on (a.id_a = b.id_a)
when matched then update set
  a.id_c = b.id_c;

commit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure

```
Alter Table C Add FK2A int Null
Update C Set c.FK2A =
      (Select FK2A From B
       Where FK2C = C.PK)
Alter Table C Alter Column FK2A int Not Null
Alter Table C Add Constraint FKTableCToA 
              Foreign Key (FK2A)
              References A (PK)
```